# Using variables in yaml

Tags: yaml

I have defined an entry in a YAML file like this

```
run1:
    exec_dir: "/home/mahmood/app/bin/"
    data_dirs: "/home/mahmood/data/1/2/3/"
    execs:
        - sim:
            - args: market input_1.txt
```

In fact `input_1.txt` exists in `data_dirs`. So, I would like to use `data_dirs` as a variable in the `args`. How can I define that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML isn't a programming language, nor is it a templating language. It doesn't have variables (you can use anchors & aliases to simulate variables to some degree though). It doesn't have procedural instructions, and you'd need concatenation/interpolation to insert the scalar content of a YAML node into another YAML node.

Your options are either to use a templating language on top of YAML, which is done by a lot of heavy YAML users like e.g. Ansible and Kubernetes Helm, or you could implement special logic on loading if you are in control of the loading code. If you are writing YAML for an existing tool, chances are that it already provides one of those options.